# How to automatically create variables WITHOUT using a list

Tags: python, mysql, variables, sqlite, tkinter

I **cannot**, or do not understand how to use a list for this problem because I am looking to be able to gather the values of the created variables  in a seperate function. The data held by these variables can be updated at any time by the user. Below is my code which should show what I am trying to do.

```
def Customer_Edit():
CustomerEdit = Tk()
global customerdetails2
customerdetails2 = db.execute('''SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, FORENAME, SURNAME, DOB, GENDER, ADDRESS, EMAIL, TELEPHONE, BAND_NAME FROM CUSTOMER''')
AA01 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Customer ID")
AA01.grid(row=0, column=0)
AA02 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Forename")
AA02.grid(row=0, column=1)
AA03 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Surname")
AA03.grid(row=0, column=2)
AA04 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "DOB")
AA04.grid(row=0, column=3)
AA05 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Gender")
AA05.grid(row=0, column=4)
AA06 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Address")
AA06.grid(row=0, column=5)
AA07 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "E-Mail")
AA07.grid(row=0, column=6)
AA08 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Telephone")
AA08.grid(row=0, column=7)
AA09 = Label(CustomerEdit, text = "Band Name")
AA09.grid(row=0, column=8)
editnum = 1
global CustomerDetailsEntries
CustomerDetailsEntries = []
for index, row in enumerate(customerdetails2):
    global entry
    entry = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry.insert(0, row[0])
    entry.grid(row = editnum, column = 0)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry.get())
    global entry1
    entry1 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry1.insert(0, row[1])
    entry1.grid(row = editnum, column = 1)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry1.get())
    global entry2
    entry2 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry2.insert(0, row[2])
    entry2.grid(row = editnum, column = 2)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry2.get())
    global entry3
    entry3 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry3.insert(0, row[3])
    entry3.grid(row = editnum, column = 3)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry3.get())
    global entry4
    entry4 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry4.insert(0, row[4])
    entry4.grid(row = editnum, column = 4)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry4.get())
    global entry5
    entry5 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry5.insert(0, row[5])
    entry5.grid(row = editnum, column = 5)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry5.get())
    global entry6
    entry6 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry6.insert(0, row[6])
    entry6.grid(row = editnum, column = 6)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry6.get())
    global entry7
    entry7 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry7.insert(0, row[7])
    entry7.grid(row = editnum, column = 7)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry7.get())
    global entry8
    entry8 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry8.insert(0, row[8])
    entry8.grid(row = editnum, column = 8)
    CustomerDetailsEntries.append(entry8.get())
    print (CustomerDetailsEntries)
    editnum = editnum + 1
    finaleditnum = editnum + 1
AA10 = tkinter.Button(CustomerEdit, text = "Save Changes", command = SaveChanges)
AA10.grid(row = finaleditnum, column = 4)

def SaveChanges():
    UpdatedEntry = entry.get()
    UpdatedEntry1 = entry1.get()
    UpdatedEntry2 = entry2.get()
    UpdatedEntry3 = entry3.get()
    UpdatedEntry4 = entry4.get()
    UpdatedEntry5 = entry5.get()
    UpdatedEntry6 = entry6.get()
    UpdatedEntry7 = entry7.get()
    UpdatedEntry8 = entry8.get()
```

The code is relatively incomplete right now but at the moment, the program gathers data from the database, defined as the variable 'customerdetails2' and enters all the data into entry fields and a new row is created for each row of data in the table that the program is gathering data from. When the button 'Save Changes' is clicked, I want the program to gather all data from the up-to-date entry fields and update the database.

SaveChanges() is where I am looking to gather all data from the created entry fields in order to update the database. However I am aware that this is not possible as the variables get updated for each row that is in the database so the program will only gather the data from the very last row of entries.

My question is is there a way to make Python automatically create uniquely named variables for each row in the database 'customerdatabase2', which would make it possible for data from every single entry field to be gathered and therefore saved into the database? Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for a while. I hope I have explained clearly why using a list for what I am trying to do is not an option as far as I can tell.

Comment: You have indentation errors.

Comment: That's how it came out when I copied and pasted it to this site, didn't notice that. But rest assured there are no indentation errors in the code itself.

Comment: The problem is that we can't see your code, so we must assume _this_ is your real code. With python, indentation is critical. If you don't care to spend the time to properly format your code, we're less inclined to take the time to properly answer it. Looking at your code, how can we possibly know if that for loop is inside or outside of `Customer_Edit`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary to store the Tkinter widgets and access them later to get the information.

Creating the widgets:

```
customer_info = {'name': None,
                 'city': None,
                 'email': None,
                 'phone': None,
                 'alias': None}

for i, each in enumerate(customer_info):
    customer_info[each] = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    customer_info[each].insert(0, customerdetails2[i])
    customer_info[each].grid(row = editnum, column = i)
```

You now have a dictionary such that `customer_info['name']` is the Entry Widget where the user can input his name.  So you can then use `customer_info['name'].get()` to retreive the input.

Reading the info later:

```
for key, val in customer_info.iteritems():
    print val.get()
```

Here is a fully standalone working example... I am assume that `customerdetails2` is a list of lists, based on your code I believe that it is. I commented out your dbquery and added in my own results.  I added in a few things to get Tkinter to open so you may need to edit based on that:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *
from collections import OrderedDict

def Customer_Edit(root):
    CustomerEdit = Frame(root)
    global customerdetails2
    global customer_dict
    #customerdetails2 = db.execute('''SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, FORENAME, SURNAME, DOB, GENDER, ADDRESS, EMAIL, TELEPHONE, BAND_NAME FROM CUSTOMER''')
    customerdetails2 = [['1234', 'Foo', 'Bar', '01/01/01', 'M', 'Foo Street', 'foo@bar.com', '1800foo', 'foobarband'], ['4444', 'Sally', 'Bear', '12/12/12', 'F', 'Sally Street', 'Sally@bar.com', '1800Sally', 'Sally Band']]
    customer_info = OrderedDict([('Customer ID', None),
                     ('Forname', None),
                     ('Surname', None),
                     ('DOB', None),
                     ('Gender', None),
                     ('Address', None),
                     ('E-Mail', None),
                     ('Telephone', None),
                     ('Band', None)])
    customer_dict = {}

    for i, customer in enumerate(customerdetails2):

        for r, each in enumerate(customer_info):
            if i == 0:
                Label(CustomerEdit, text=each).grid(row= 0, column= r)
            customer_info[each] = Entry(CustomerEdit)
            customer_info[each].insert(0, customer[r])
            customer_info[each].grid(row= i+1, column= r)

        customer_dict[i] = dict(customer_info)

    AA10 = Button(CustomerEdit, text = "Save Changes", command = SaveChanges)
    AA10.grid(row=len(customer_dict) + 1, column= 4)

    CustomerEdit.pack()

def SaveChanges():
    for k, v in customer_dict.iteritems():
        print 'Customer Number: ' + str(k)
        for title, info in v.iteritems():
            print '{} - {}'.format(title, info.get())

root = Tk()
Customer_Edit(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do see what you mean. However I am unsure about one thing. Would I have to import all the data from my sql database and add it into the dictionary before implementing this code? Thank you for the response.

Comment: @user3112327 Instead of `row[i]` you would use `customerdetails2[i]`.  This is assuming that all of your information is in order.

Comment: @user3112327 If you'll do a `print customerdetails2` right after the `db.execute` and post it here I'll do a full working example for you.

Comment: when customerdetails2 is printed, the following appears: `['1', 'TestForename', 'TestSurname', '15/08/1993', 'Male', 'TestAddress', 'TestEmail', '07777777777', 'TestBandName', '2', 'TestForename2', 'TestSurname2', '15/03/1993', 'Male', 'TestAddress2', 'TestEmail2', '07777777777', 'TestBandName2', '3', 'TestForename3', 'TestSurname3', '15/03/1990', 'Female', 'TestAddress3', 'TestEmail3', '07777777777', 'TestBandName3', '4', 'TestForename4', 'TestSurname4', '12/09/1983', 'Female', 'TestAddress4', 'TestEmail4', '07777777777', 'TestBandName4']`

Comment: @user3112327 Are you sure it's not a list of lists, that doesn't seem to work in your code otherwise.

Comment: It's a .db file accessed with `db = sqlite3.connect('NSS_Database.db')`. It is created by running the code `db.execute('''CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
               (CUSTOMER_ID           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                FORENAME     TEXT    NOT NULL,
                SURNAME      TEXT    NOT NULL,
                DOB          TEXT     NOT NULL,
                GENDER       TEXT    NOT NULL,
                ADDRESS      CHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
                EMAIL        TEXT    NOT NULL,
                TELEPHONE    TEXT     NOT NULL,
                BAND_NAME    TEXT    NOT NULL);''')`

Comment: @user3112327 I edited with a working example, hopefully it has the frame to get you started.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, I was stuck on this for so long, I can't thank you enough. :)

Comment: Hi again, sorry one more question about something I'm unsure about. in the code you've used `for i, customer` and `for r, each`. I am not sure about how 'customer' and 'each' work within the code. How does Python use these two variables?

Comment: @user3112327 Those are variables extracted from `enumerate()`  When you use `enumerate()` on an iterable, say a  list like this: `for i, user in enumerate(['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']):`  on each loop through, `i` is a placeholder number and `user` is each element of that list.  So first time through `i = 0, user = 'User 1'`, 2nd time through `i = 1, user = 'User 2'` etc.